# Making an Ajax call to the controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm using MVC 2 and trying to make an ajax call to the controller method.

**Controller:**

```
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult FirstAjax()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult FirstAjax(string a)
        {

            return Json("chamara", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }
```

**View:**

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            var serviceURL = '<%= Url.Action("FirstAjax", "AjaxTest") %>';

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: serviceURL,
                data: param = "",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: successFunc,
                error: errorFunc
            });

            function successFunc(data, status) {

                alert(data);


            }

            function errorFunc() {
                alert('error');
            }
        });
    </script>
</head>
```

In above code please notice my controller. to get the code working i had to add to methods with **HTTPPOST** and **HTTPGET** and even the parameter a is not related i just added it because i can not add two methods with the same signature.

I guess this might not be the correct way to do this. please explain the most suitable approach for this kind of code.

**UPDATE:**

adding a single method with out POST and GET does not work. It just print the string "chamara" on the page.alert not firing

```
 public ActionResult FirstAjax()
        {

            return Json("chamara", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you cannot have two methods with the same name and signature you have to use the ActionName attribute:

**UPDATE:**

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult FirstAjax()
    {
        Some Code--Some Code---Some Code
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ActionName("FirstAjax")]
    public ActionResult FirstAjaxPost()
    {
        Some Code--Some Code---Some Code
        return View();
    }
```

And please refer [this](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/08/29/how-a-method-becomes-an-action.aspx) link for further reference of how a  method becomes an action. Very good reference though.

Answer (score 0):

From your explanation I think the code what you need is like :

AjaxTestController.cs

```
[HttpGet]          
public ActionResult FirstAjax()
{
     return Json("chamara", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function () {

      var serviceURL = '<%= Url.Action("FirstAjax", "AjaxTest") %>';

      $.ajax({
           type: "GET",
           url: serviceURL,               
           success: successFunc,
           error: errorFunc
      });

      function successFunc(data) {           
           alert(data);
      }

      function errorFunc(xhr, status, err) {            
           alert('error');
      }

      });
</script>
```